# What if a company doesn't leave paperwork or invoice us for services?

Tags: invoices

We have used a service company for years (although I have only worked there about a year).  I think they come for service about once a year.  For some reason it looks like they not only stopped leaving paperwork when completing their work but also stopped invoicing us in 2012.  The service person(s) have been entering and exiting via our "loading dock" area, so the office staff sometimes doesn't know until a plant manager mentions it (if they remember to mention it).

I am new to this position and it is my understanding that my predecessor called the company repeatedly asking for copies of the invoices each time. Each time, they would tell them that they haven't gotten around to it yet.

Every time the plant managers mentioned the lack of previous invoices during subsequent service calls, they were told to contact the billing department.
We have contacted the billing department again and again but still they are not sending them.  They are very good at their work.  In our area, it is hard to find other companies to do this work for us.

We know that when we do finally get billed, it will be massive. Would it be out of the question to ask for a discount on the oldest items since we were never got supplied paperwork for those jobs anyway?  Advise please.

Comment: So your company has been getting these services for 7 years now and haven't payed a thing to the other company?

Comment: This seems like a legal question. Get legal advice on whether you are still liable to pay for the services from 7 years ago. Once you have this advice you can proceed to either a) pay them as little as possible b) pay them the full amount c) offer somewhere in between.

Comment: Who verifies that they're actually performing these services? Who accompanies them to make sure they're not up to something nefarious? It's pretty odd that they'd perform this service for 7 years without payment unless something else is going on that you aren't aware of.

Answer (score 6):

Are you saying you haven't paid them at all since they stopped billing you?

If you are paying (let's say the same you paid in 2012), and you want bills, then you would just stop paying, and one would expect that the bills start arriving very quickly.

If you are not paying, because you don't receive bills, I'd make sure that the money is deposited in a safe place, and your accountants probably have to do something (because you *owe* the money after all) to book this correctly.

In most countries, you don't have to pay a bill at all after six years or so. So if you haven't been paying for six years, your debt (for six years of work) isn't growing anymore.

Someone has a huge problem here, but fortunately, it isn't you.

Maybe you should also check the last bill that you had, and what exactly you were paying for, and verify that the work that is being done is still the same. But it seems you are happy with the job that they are doing? Very strange.

Answer (score 3):

Let's set legal aspects aside:

- check administrative issues on your side (e.g. that If you are working in a very big company, maybe another department also uses services from tis company and somebody else signs off and doenst notice your part of the cost)
- after you talk to you manager/contract people, go towards the company. If that is indeed an administrative error, it also must be an administrative error on their side

I could imagine the following situation: Work level says "I will remind my manager", manager sees the whole account and bills certain costs accidentally to another customer in the same customer company, and says "ok, handled", worker is not informed, and promises the next time again politely to take of it, but supplier accountants are not following it up because their books are correct.

(I have seen something like this before, where literally everybody was unaware to which specific project/customer inside a big customer company was booked - until somebody wondered why there is so much budget left)